# Can we load string resources from a resource file other than strings.xml in Android?

Tags: android, string, resources

I want to provide different resource files to users. But I don't know how to load strings from a resource file other than strings.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String resources do not have to live in a file named `strings.xml`. String resources are accessed the same way regardless of the filename: `R.string.whatever` or `@string/whatever`. The string resources do need to be in the `res/values/` directory (or variations on that for other resource sets).